# Adding signature or images into PDF using PHP and FPDF

Tags: php, canvas, pdf-generation, ghostscript, fpdf

I'm doing a project in which I have to merge a signature image of the user on to a .pdf file. First I converted all the pages of the pdf file into series of images using Ghostscript and loaded all of them in a div. Then the user drops a signature by signing in a canvas and places it using the mouse pointer. I get the user's location using e.clientX and e.clientY which returns value in pixel coordinates.

I took the coordinates, page number and the captured image from canvas and passed it to FPDF but it placed the image in a different location. Then I found that FDPF uses mm precision. How do i sort this out?

Is there any other simpler way to accomplish my task? Solutions or Suggestions place.

Comment: Try this formula : `[VALUE_IN_PIXELS] * [MM_IN_INCH] / [DPI]`, Where `MM_IN_INCH = 25.4`

Comment: @SyedQarib How do I find the DPI of my pdf file?

Comment: This is the document DPI, it would be `96` i think

Comment: I have posted this as an answer, accept it to close the thread ..

Answer (score 0):

Try getting result using this formula :

```
[VALUE_IN_PIXELS] * [MM_IN_INCH] / [DPI]

Where:
MM_IN_INCH = 25.4
DPI = 96
```